# Simple loop iteration over Eclipse Collections maps (for example: IntObjectHashMap)

Tags: java, loops, foreach, iterator, eclipse-collections

Is there a way to use simple Java for-each loop over [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) maps?

I am looking for something like this (but for Eclipse Collections maps):

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
}
```

... but I can't find anything like it for Eclipse Collections maps.

Of course I know this type of Eclipse Collections iterations:

```
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.map.mutable.primitive.IntObjectHashMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntObjectHashMap<String> map = new IntObjectHashMap<>();
        map.put(1, "one");
        map.put(2, "two");
        int i = 0;
        map.forEachKeyValue((int key, String val) -> {
            i++; // Compilation error. 
            System.out.println("key: " + key + ", val: " + val);
        });
    }
}
```

... but this construct has some drawbacks, for example I don't have easy access to the surrounding local variables (as shown in the example above, which example will not compile due to incorrect access to the local variable `i`).

Any ideas how to write *simple* loop over Eclipse Collections maps?

Comment: I haven't used eclipse collections yet, but from the docs it would seel that [IntObjectHashMap.keyValuesView()](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/map/mutable/primitive/IntObjectHashMap.html#keyValuesView--) returns an Iterable over the Entries in the Map (as `IntObjectPair`-instances, in that case). It should be possible to use that in an enhanced for loop.

Comment: It looks very promising! Thank you very much, Hulk.

Comment: Doc: [*Map iteration methods*](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/docs/guide.md#-map-iteration-methods)

Answer (score 4):

The recommendations from Hulk and Basil in the comments are good. I'll include a test for your code that works for future reference.

```
@Test
public void keyValuesView()
{
    IntObjectHashMap<String> map = new IntObjectHashMap<>();
    map.put(1, "one");
    map.put(2, "two");
    int i = 0;
    for (IntObjectPair<String> pair : map.keyValuesView())
    {
        i++;
        System.out.println("key: " + pair.getOne() + ", val: " + pair.getTwo());
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(2, i);
}
```

The best option is to use an internal iterator as you have in your question, as there will be less garbage generated while iterating (an IntObjectPair for each key/value pair). This comes with the downside of not being able to reference anything from the outer scope of the lambda that is not final. If you want to have a simple counter for things inside of the internal iterator, you can use the `Counter` class available in Eclipse Collections.

```
@Test
public void forEachKeyValueWithCounter()
{
    IntObjectHashMap<String> map = new IntObjectHashMap<>();
    map.put(1, "one");
    map.put(2, "two");
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    map.forEachKeyValue((int key, String val) -> {
        counter.increment();
        System.out.println("key: " + key + ", val: " + val);
    });
    Assert.assertEquals(2, counter.getCount());
}
```